# if I am on the last page right navigation arrow should be invisible

Tags: jquery, list, navigation

I have news list in which new news is adding dynamically by appending 'li' to 'ul'.Its almost worked but the issue is all function are working on ONCLICK so when I go last news list page the right navigation is visible and when I click on that its get hide.

So I want if I am on the last page right navigation arrow should be invisible.

This css to hide navigation arrows.

`.iconWrap.left,.hide-right{display: none;}
.iconWrap.left-nav {display: block;}`

This is navigation arrows structure:

```
 <div class="iconWrap left"><a onclick="leftarrow()" id="leftNav"></a></div>
 <div class="iconWrap right"><a onclick="rightarrow()" id="rightNav"></a></div>
```

This is UL structure where li get append:

```
<ul id="news-list">----- Here all li adds dynamically----</ul>
```

this is the function to calculate records per page, total records:

```
function NewsList(page, num_Per_Page){
    $("#news-list").html("");
    var start = parseInt(num_Per_Page) * parseInt(page);
    var end = start + parseInt(num_Per_Page);
    if(current_Page > 0){
        $(".iconWrap.left").addClass("left-nav");
    } else {
        $(".iconWrap.left").removeClass("left-nav");
    }
    for(var z=start; z<end; z++){
    if(news[z] == undefined) continue;
        $("#news-list").append('<li><a href="#">--li data here--</a></li>');
    }
}
```

below functions calling for navigation arrows:

```
function leftarrow(){
    if(current_Page > 0){
        current_Page--;                        
        populateNewsList(current_Page, num_Records_PerPage);
    }
}

function rightarrow() {
    if((current_Page + 1) != (Math.ceil(<?=count($this->news)?>/num_Records_PerPage))){
        current_Page++;
        populateNewsList(current_Page, num_Records_PerPage);                      
    } else {
        $(".iconWrap.right").addClass("hide-right");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make it work even when function is executed onclick

Create a global variable that keeps count of total number of pages:

`var totalPages = Math.ceil(<?=count($this->news)?>/num_Records_PerPage))`

You should make the logic of user interface different from the rest of the code. Call the function after every time 'arrows' are clicked.

```
function showArrows() {
    if (currentPage > 1)
        $(".iconWrap.left").addClass("left-nav");
    else
        $(".iconWrap.left").removeClass("left-nav");

    if (currentPage >= totalPages)
        $(".iconWrap.right").addClass("hide-right");
    else
        $(".iconWrap.right").removeClass("hide-right");
}
```

```
function NewsList(page, num_Per_Page){
    $("#news-list").html("");
    var start = parseInt(num_Per_Page) * parseInt(page);
    var end = start + parseInt(num_Per_Page);

    for(var z=start; z<end; z++){
        if(news[z] == undefined) continue;
        $("#news-list").append('<li><a href="#">--li data here--</a></li>');
    }
}


function leftarrow(){
    if(current_Page > 0){
        current_Page--;                        
        populateNewsList(current_Page, num_Records_PerPage);
    }
    showArrows();
}

function rightarrow() {
    if((current_Page + 1) != totalPages){
        current_Page++;
        populateNewsList(current_Page, num_Records_PerPage);                      
    } 
    showArrows();   // Call it every time arrows are clicked
}
```

You could also call `showArrows()` when the documents completes loading to set initial value

Comment: hey thank you for the solution.....but it's not working...when I go to the last page of news right navigation arrow is still visible.@Ashish Kumar

Comment: I am sorry.. I forgot to add logic for removing class. Please check updated showArrow function.

Comment: I tried what you wrote above.But maybe some conditions going wrong because on last page "hide-right" class is not getting add..and when I go back by clicking prev arrow then page 1 records not showing me.

Comment: ` function showArrows() {
                    if (currentPage > 0) {
                        $(".iconWrap.left").addClass("left-nav");
                    } else {
                        $(".iconWrap.left").removeClass("left-nav");
                    }

                    if ((currentPage + 1) >= totalPages) {
                        $(".iconWrap.right").addClass("right-nav");
                    } else {
                        $(".iconWrap.right").removeClass("right-nav");
                    }
                }`  ------------- This works for me.

Comment: That's because your page starts with 0 and ends with totalPages - 1. Anyways, great to know that you got it working.